# What causes my error "Illegal choice in Sorted by element"?

Tags: 7, forms, debugging

Drupal 7.50 commons

The following error shows dozens per minute when I run `drush ws --tail`,  but there are no reports of users encountering errors or features that are non-operational. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Reporting for anonymous user.

```
error     form  Illegal choice  in Sorted by element.
```

Below is a screenshot of one of the errors, for detail.
[image: Screenshot from dblog]

Below is a screenshot of part of the page content that might be generating the problem, from admin/reports/dblog.
[image: Screenshot of content]

The error seems to be affecting more than one group or all of our groups. Here is an example URL from another entry:
http://example.com/groups/oregon?sort_by=&sort_order=DESC&page=0,0,1

Here is the Commons Browsing Widget View Sorting Criteria:
[image]

Comment: when you say `but the error isn't being reported on the site` you mean it doesn't show in your log /admin/reports/dblog?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I meant users don't encounter the error when using the site. i.e. nothing seems to be non-operational. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Ok, so when you look in that /admin/reports/dblog watchdog do you see these Illegal choice errors there as well? If yes, can you add the full error info into your answer?

Comment: Thank you for the help finding more information. I posted a screenshot. I can at least see which content that it's coming from now. Sure enough, there is an error showing on that page.

Comment: looks like the sort in the url does not have a value `&sort_by=&sort_order=DESC` it cannot order descending if you don't give it a sort by. You might be able to fix this by changing the sort filter in your view to require the sort by, however you could still have this happen if someone deletes the sort_by value from the url manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out what view was being used on group pages (The Commons Browsing Widget) and see that there were three sorting criteria. One of them is the Radioactivity module.

I checked the general status report (admin/reports/status) to see that there was an issue with RadioActivity module.

I removed this sorting feature for now, but it should work now that I cleared up the issues with the module. I guess no one could have known that this was the cause. I'm keeping this up in case anyone else finds it helpful.